# wmi accelerator and authentication

Tags: powershell, wmi, sccm

It seems I can not find clearly written somewhere that when using WMI accelerator in a PowerShell script, you can not pass on authentication.

A little background ...

I am writing PowerShell scripts for SCCM 2012 and found, for instance, the following quite using :

```
PS R:\> ([wmi]((gwmi -namespace root\sms\site_AAA -class SMS_Application -filter  
"LocalizedDisplayName LIKE '%Winzip_Tartempion%'")
.__PATH)).SDMPackageXML
```

When executed locally (on the SCCM primary server, it works fine and swiftly.
However, the following ends up in error when executed from my desktop computer running W7 :

```
PS R:\> ([wmi]((gwmi -namespace root\sms\site_AAA -credential $cred 
-ComputerName CEMTECH 
-class SMS_Application -filter "LocalizedDisplayName LIKE   
'%Winzip_Tartempion%'")
.__PATH)).SDMPackageXML
```

For the time being, using a PSSession is out of the question.
With the current infrastructure I have to deal with, using SCCM commandlet is out of the question.

My only question here is : can you confirm that we can not pass any authentication with a WMI accelerator ? At that point, I am searching for that answer mainly for my curiosity. I found a way to manage with my current constraints. It is just that I find the accelerators so "elegant".

Now why do I need it ? I need to access "lazy properties" without using SCCM cmdlets, from a desktop computer to which the user is logged on with an account which will not be the same as the name authorized to connect/access the SCCM primary server.

What I still did not find is how to use "*.__PATH" with the Get-WMIObject cmdlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WMI-accelerator `[wmi]` doesn't support alternate credentials.

Why do you need it? You could just run:

```
$obj = Get-WmiObject -namespace root\sms\site_P41 -credential $cred -ComputerName qs07352 -class SMS_Application -filter "LocalizedDisplayName LIKE '%Winzip_Tartempion%'"
$obj.Get()

$obj.SDMPackageXML
```

Comment: Thank you for the crystal-clear answer, I'll stop searching that way (accelerator and authentication).

Comment: However, SDMPackageXML being a lazy property, your suggestion does not work.

Comment: see updated answer. I don't have SCCM 2012 available atm. so I can't test it.

Comment: Huge ... Beautiful ... Perfect ... It works and I tested that successfully with another lazy properties (RefreshSchedule from SMS_Collection). Thanks a lot,